# How to expand the ext4 partition of virtualized Ubuntu running on top of CentOS/QEMU?

Tags: ext4, partitioning, xen, fdisk

My company is running Xen--VMs run on top of CentOS/QEMU.

Recently a customer using virtualized Ubuntu asked that his HDD space be increased. Now, with Windows, this is a joke. You type the new size into the hypervisor and, like magic, it shows up in the machine.

Ubuntu is NOT like this. If I increase the disk space in the hypervisor to, say, 80GB -- this change is recognized... I am told that disk `/dev/vda` is equal to a larger amount (75.2GB) when I run an `fdisk` on `/dev/vda`.

**Here's the issue -- I have a customer that wants to increase the HDD space on his virtualized Ubuntu machine to 100GB. I'm not sure of how to do this!**

I type "100GB" into the hypervisor. This shows up on `fdisk`. It also shows up when I do an `fdisk -l`. The issue is that I have two partitions "in front" of `/dev/vda1--/dev/vda2` and `/dev/vda5`.

- `/dev/vda2` is *2095105 blocks* and is ID'ed as "5".
- `/dev/vda5` is *2095104 blocks* and is ID'ed at 82 (swap).

I was supossing that I could remove the last two partitions, grow the first, then replace them. Problem is... I cannot do anything to a working partition because the machine is using it! If this were a desktop I'd simply boot from a live CD and try this. Am I thinking along the right lines here?

My questions are this:

- First of all, is it even *possible* to enlarge a partiton that the system is running on?
- Second is this: if I can PHYSICALLY get near the server running this VDI can I just shut it down in Xen and rebuild the partitions? When I rebuild are there steps I MUST take -- like making sure that the start blocks are the same? This partition has data on it and I'd like to keep it intact... though I told the customer that there was a BIG chance of data loss and to back up.

Folks, how would YOU go about doing this? Also, where does fstab fit into all of this?

Comment: Although your client is using Ubuntu, your hypervisor is running in CentOS; so this is probably off-topic here. But look at the man page for `qemu-img`. Don't do this to a running vdi, but you want `qemu-img resize filename [+|-]size`. `After using this command to grow a disk image, you must use file system and partitioning tools inside the VM to actually begin using the new space on the device.` Or, after changing the size in the hyperviser, using the tools in the guest may be all you need to get the change recognized.

Comment: It is possible. See this link: http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3786220 . I am not sure how your virtual disk is partitioned, so, it may be easier to back up your data and do a fresh install on a larger disk, add a second disk and use LVM, I am not sure. At any rate, Xen is not fully supported on Ubuntu as I do not think there is a xen kernel in the repos. Web interfaces, and their features. are another matter.

Comment: @chaskes: Isn't this question an edge-case and *probably* on-topic for our site? The user wants to increase the partition size of Ubuntu which is running as a VM. It **is** about Ubuntu. Isn't it? (I don't have sufficient knowledge to answer this question - so I might be wrong..)

Comment: @Aditya In this case, it strikes me as a question about resizing _any_ vdi using qemu on CentOS, so I see it as off-topic; but I don't have strong feelings about it. Truth is, I normally argue for an expansive view of what's on-topic and am by no means quick to close. But in this case...idk, it could be salvaged through a focus on fdisk in Ubuntu, I suppose.